# Display only 19 elements from list with offset

Tags: java

I am trying to only display 19 elements from a list at a time (to keep output within the limitations of the output area). The current code which I figured would work just fine only shows a single line at a time.

```
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3916568049983591216L;
    {
        add("Line 1");
        add("Line 2");
        add("Line 3");  
        add("Line 4");
        add("Line 5");
        add("Line 6");
        add("Line 7");
        add("Line 8");
        add("Line 9");  
        add("Line 10"); 
        add("Line 11");
        add("Line 12");
        add("Line 13"); 
        add("Line 14");
        add("Line 15");
        add("Line 16");
        add("Line 17");
        add("Line 18");
        add("Line 19"); 
        add("Line 20"); 
    }};

    int page = 1;
    boolean np = false;
    StringBuilder help = new StringBuilder();

    // Stuff to determine page

    int startLine = 0;
    if (page > 1) {
        startLine = 19 * page;
    }

    for (int i = startLine; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        String line = lines.get(i);
        help.append(line);
        help.append("\n");
        if (i % 19 == 0) { // If 19th element break
            if (lines.size() > i) // Set next page to true if there is still more elements to show
                np = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(help.toString());
    if (np) 
        System.out.println("There is a next page.");
```

Which instead of displaying the first 19 lines (as the page is 1) it shows 1 line:

`Line 1

    There is a next page.`

Comment: It may be useful to you to know that `0 % 19 == 0` is `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental issue here is that on page 1 as well as any additional pages, you're going to always trip the `if (i % 19 == 0)` requirement, as `0%19 == 0, 19%19 == 0`, and so forth. You must create a special case to not check against the starting number.

I suggest replacing `if (i % 19 == 0)` with `if (i % 19 == 0 && i != startLine)`

Comment: Now it makes complete sense. I didn't even think of that.

Comment: Doesn't help for the next bunch of lines.  Add more lines to your test case and you'll only ever see the first line of the next page.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson Yep, I totally agree. I didn't look that far ahead. I amended it, so that it works on all following pages.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Stuff to determine page
    int startLine = 19 * (page - 1);  // Always true, even on page 1

    for (int i = 0; i < 19 && startLine + i < lines.size(); i++) {
        String line = lines.get(startLine + i);
        help.append(line);
        help.append("\n");
    }
    np = (startLine + 19 < lines.size());

    System.out.println(help.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

you should delete:

if (i % 19 == 0) {

```
    // If 19th element break
    if (lines.size() > i) // Set next page to true if there is still more elements to show
            np = true;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: if (i % 19 == 0) { // If 19th element break
            if (lines.size() > i) // Set next page to true if there is still more elements to show
                np = true;
            break;
        }

Comment: what is the purpose of that comment?